# Why is argv (argument vector) in C defined as a pointer and what is the need for defining its zeroth as the program name?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i;
 for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
  printf("%s%s", argv[i], (i<argc-1)? " ":"");
 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Given above is a simple C program that outputs command line inputs. Here `argc` is the argument counter. `argv` is said to be an array that contains arguments. My question is: why does it define as a pointer to a character array instead of a normal array? Also what is the need for defining its zeroth element (argv[0]) as the name by which the program is invoked.

I am a beginner and please explain it high level perspective.

Comment: What I meant is what is the need for a pointer there.

Comment: I was talking to a friend about your second question last night actually - what I said was that it could be needed if the user changes the name of the program, we might need to know what it's now called, say to call another instance, update, etc.

Comment: It would be better to call it "an array of pointers to char" in other words if `char *` represents a C-style string then `char *x[]` means that `x` is an array of C-style strings

Comment: To answer your other question, make your loop go from `i=0` then try to invoke your command from the shell in different ways e.g. `./foo bar baz` or `/path/to/foo bar baz` and expirement to see if there is any difference in how your environment transmits argv[0]

Comment: @Brandin: If `char *x[]` is a parameter declaration, it means that `x` is a pointer to pointer to `char`. It may or may not point to an element of an array of `char*` pointers, and those `char*` pointers may or may not point to C-style strings; the parameter declaration doesn't specify that.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes. This is why one can write equivalently `char **x` in the declaration. Yes. `char *` does not automatically imply a C-style string. Also, it's interesting to notice that the definition of C-style strings does not provide any reliable way of testing whether or not something is one. Not sure if it's in the C standard or POSIX, but I think somewhere is specified that in the special case of  `argv` this must be contain an array of C-style strings whose last element has the value  `(char *)0` in conforming implementations

Comment: This explains it all: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRdfX7ut8gw

Answer (score 4):

`argv` is defined as a pointer rather than as an array because there is no such thing as an array parameter in C.

You can define something that *looks* like an array parameter, but it's "adjusted" to array type at compile time; for example, these two declarations are exactly equivalent:

```
int foo(int param[]);
int foo(int param[42]); /* the 42 is quietly ignored */
int foo(int *param);    /* this is what the above two declarations really mean */
```

And the definition of `main` can be written either as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

or as

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { /* ... */ }
```

The two are exactly equivalent (and the second one, IMHO, more clearly expresses what's actually going on).

Array types are, in a sense, second-class types in C. Code that manipulates array almost always does so via pointers to the elements, performing pointer arithmetic to traverse the elements.

Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) explains the often confusing relationship between arrays and pointers.

(And if you've been told that arrays are "really" pointers, they're not; arrays and pointers are distinct things.)

As for why `argv[0]` points to the program name, that's just because it's useful. Some programs print their names in error messages; others may change their behavior depending on the name by which they're invoked. Bundling the program name with the command-line arguments was a fairly arbitrary choice, but it's convenient and it works.

Answer (score 3):

The `char *argv[]` is a pointer that an array of `char *` has decayed into. For example, invoking a command like this:

```
$ ./command --option1 -opt2 input_file
```

could be viewed as:

```
char *argv[] = {
    "./command",
    "--option1",
    "-opt2",
    "input_file",
    NULL,
};
main(4, argv);
```

So basically there is an array of strings outside `main`, and it is passed to you in `main`:

```
    char *argv[]
    \- --/     ^
      V        |
      |   It was an array
      |
of strings
```

---

Regarding `argv[0]` being the invocation command, the reason is largely historical. I don't know what the first person who thought of it thought about, but I can tell at least one usefulness for it.

Imagine a program, such as `vim` or `gawk`. These programs may install symbolic links (such as `vi` or `awk`) which point to the same program. So effectively, running `vim` or `vi` (or similarly `gawk` or `awk`) could execute the exact same program. However, by inspecting `argv[0]`, these programs can tell how they have been called and possibly adjust accordingly.

As far as I know, neither of the programs I mentioned above actually do this, but they could. For example `vim` called through a symbolic link named `vi` could turn on some compatibility. Or `gawk` called as `awk` could turn off some GNU extensions. In the modern world, if they wanted to do this, they would probably create scripts that gives the correct options, though.

Comment: `char *argv[]` (which, as a parameter, is exactly equivalent to `char**`) is not a pointer to an array of `char*`; it's a pointer to *the first element of* an array of `char*`. A pointer to a `char*` and a pointer to an array of `char*` would have distinct types.

Comment: `vim` behaves differently depending on whether it is invoked as `vim`, `view`, `vimdiff`, `rview`, `rvim` (and maybe as `vi`).

Comment: @KeithThompson, I made the wording more precise.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, exactly. However, in the couple of times that I actually wrote `vi` instead of `vim`, I didn't see any difference, that's why I said: _As far as I know, neither of the programs I mentioned above actually do this_ (with respect to `vim` and `vi`)

Comment: "`char *argv[]` is a pointer that an array of `char *` has decayed into." -- I wouldn't put it that way. The entity that calls `main` isn't necessarily even written in C. An array *expression* decays to a pointer to its first element, but there isn't necessarily any array expression. There are two distinct rules at play: a parameter of array type is *adjusted* to a parameter of pointer type at compile time, and an expression of array type is *converted* ("decays") to a pointer value, notionally at run time.

Comment: @KeithThompson, so long as the observed behavior is so, it doesn't really matter. The entity calling `main` is not necessarily written in C, but if it was, that is what could have happened. (before I continue, `char *argv[]` and `char **argv` are the same (as you said so too), so I wouldn't discuss the first rule you mentioned above). More precisely, most likely, there is a `char **argv = malloc(...)` involved (if the `main`-calling entity was written in C), so there is neither an array nor decaying to pointer involved at all!

Comment: Slightly nitpicky, but in your example, string literals do not have type `const char *` in C so there's no need to use `strdup()` to avoid that, and you should have a null pointer as the last element of your `argv` array.

Comment: Again, the observed behavior is the same; it _looks_ like the entity who called `main` had created an array and that array has decayed into a pointer. That explains the OP's question regarding arrays being involved.

Comment: It's unlikely that `malloc` is involved; `free(argv)` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: String literals aren't `const`, but you can't modify them; you're explicitly permitted to modify the argument strings.

Comment: @KeithThompson: No argument with that, pun unintended.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, thanks, I didn't realize string literals in C aren't actually of `const char []` type. And yeah, I forgot about the NULL.

Comment: @KeithThompson, undefined behavior doesn't mean that the libraries are forbidden from doing it. It means that the standard doesn't _mandate_ `malloc` to be used, but doesn't forbid it either. In fact, the implementation of glibc, in `execvpe` uses `alloca` or `malloc` based on configuration.

Comment: +1 for simply and patiently addressing each of these (somewhat minor) nits, all from people with knowledge substantial enough to find holes in an explanation that otherwise seemed to address the OP in a very clear and simple way.

Comment: @ryyker, thanks. It's hard to find the sweet spot between being absolutely correct and not super-terrifying to a newbie. I personally liked that Keith explained the different syntaxes for pointer function arguments (in his answer), which I think is important for the OP to know.

Answer (score 2):

***The questions you ask*** are really answered best by simply saying its all "by definition".  i.e. a set of rules *designed* and *agreed upon* by a committee.

***Here is what C11 says:***  (see emphasized sections)

***5.1.2.2.1 Program startup***
***1*** The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
parameters:
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.
***2*** If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following
constraints:
— The value of argc shall be nonnegative.
— argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.
— If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array members argv[0] through
argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup.
***The intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
from elsewhere in the hosted environment***. If the host environment is not capable of
supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
— If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by argv[0]
represents the program name; argv[0][0] shall be the null character if the
program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of argc is
greater than one, the strings pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1]
represent the program parameters.
— The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall
be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
startup and program termination.

Comment: This is not the best way to answer the question because it suggests we should simply obey committees without reason and because it does not explain why the committees did what they did. The committees that developed the C standard had reasons for what they did, there is documentation about it, and it is useful for people to understand why the language is designed the way it is.

Comment: I have found it very helpful at times to understand that something has been decided for the sake of standardization, possibly without any great significance. This is how it is - move on.

Answer (score 1):

It is not defined as a normal array because in C the size of array elements has to be known at compile time. The size of `char *` is known, the size (length) of your arguments are not.

`argv[0]` contains the name of the invoked process because it is possible to invoke it by any arbitrary name. e.g. `exec` family of calls can specify what it wants and you are allowed to invoke a program via a symlink. `argv[0]` allows the program to offer different functionality depending on the invocation name.